# How SSL certificate and keystore works together?

Tags: ssl, https, webserver, ssl-certificate

I'm wondering why we need SSL certificate ? Because the moment we generate the keystore, it does the same functionality. It gives SSL platform.

May I know please why we need certificate and if it really needs then how it works (Certificate merged with keystore) when a third party sends a request to access web-server's website ?

Answer (score 0):

To use the SSL certificate in a web server, you configure your web server software (Apache, NGINX, etc...) to read the certificate. Tutorials on this topic abound; here is a sample set of instructions from DigiCert, who sells SSL certificates: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-ubuntu-server-with-apache2.htm